# Passing data from a jquery ajax request to a wcf service fails deserialization?

Tags: jquery, wcf, json

I use the following code to call a wcf service. If i call a (test) method that takes no parameters, but returns a string it works fine. If i add a parameter to my method i get a wierd error:

> {"ExceptionDetail":{"HelpLink":null,"InnerException":null,"Message":"The token '\"' was expected but found '''.","StackTrace":" at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)\u000d\u000a at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowTokenExpected(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String expected, Char found)\u000d\u000a at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.ParseStartElement()\u000d\u000a at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.Read()\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyCore(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)","Type":"System.Xml.XmlException"},"ExceptionType":"System.Xml.XmlException","Message":"The token '\"' was expected but found '''.","StackTrace":" at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)\u000d\u000a at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowTokenExpected(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String expected, Char found)\u000d\u000a at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.ParseStartElement()\u000d\u000a at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.Read()\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyCore(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractJsonSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.CompositeDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)\u000d\u000a at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)"}

My jquery looks like this, but i tried changing the actual data which i send as a string serialized json (as you can see) to a pure json object with the same sad result.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "ajax/Statistics.svc/Get7DaysStatistics",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'customerId': '2'}",
    timeout: 10000,
    success: function(obj) { updateStatistics(obj.d); },
    error: function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.responseText)          
            $("body").html(xhr.responseText);
        else
            alert('unknown error');
        return;
    }
});
```

The wcf service looks like this:

```
    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic"), OperationContract]
    public string Get7DaysStatistics(string customerId)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(customerId);
        return "Test done";
    }
```

It's placed in a a class with the following attributes:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

I won't list the configuration in the web.config to keep this long message "short" but i can post it if anybody thinks they can use it - i just want to stress that i CAN call a method and get a result - string or even a json object i can read from as long as i DON'T pass any data to the wcf service.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes in the JSON you are sending to the service. That is, change:

```
data: "{'customerId': '2'}",
```

to

```
data: '{"customerId": "2"}',
```

I've tested this locally and this fixes the problem.

Incidentally, I debugged this using a method I've often used when calling ASMX and WCF services using libraries other than the built-in ASP.NET tools. I called the service using the client proxy created by an [asp:ScriptReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference.aspx) and then inspected the request being sent to the server using an HTTP sniffer (such as [HttpFox](http://code.google.com/p/httpfox/) for FireFox) and compared the request to the one being sent by [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Then you can usually quickly see what is different (and so probably wrong) with the request. In this case, it was clear that there was a difference in the POST data being sent.

Comment: That's wild - i actually did that before i read your post, but it didn't work. Then i figured perhaps if i removed the WebInvoke attribute davogones posted (and i added) it might just work and it did!

Comment: After a bit of reflection (on my error) i realize i just suck at serializing json :P My data wasn't correctly formatted json - this is no magic, json needs double quotes and not single. Javascript might not care but json does, so ofcourse it should look like this.

Comment: Thanks Daniel....................PHEW. Absolutely right when you say that JavaScript might not care, but JSON does. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have only ever thought that posting is essential for username and password log on functionality so this is the way I encode the JSon parameters I send to the web service...

Here is the Webservice Contract..

```cs
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILogonService
    {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
      Method = "POST",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
    string Logon(string un, string pw);
    }
```

Here is the JQuery (Note the use of " and ' is important!)

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/LogonService.svc/Logon",
  data: '{ "un": "' + $('#un').val() + '", "pw": "' + $('#pw').val() + '"}',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a function in jscript that solved the problem for sending data via POST to a WCF service ... follow the code ...

function formatJsonDataToWCFPost(d){

```
var t = {};
var a = '{';
for (var j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
    var x = d[j];
    for (var i in x) {
        if (x.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            var c = j + 1 == d.length ? '}' : ',';
            a += ('"' + i + '":"' + x[i] + '"' + c);
        }
    }
}

return a;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think on your operation you need this attribute:

```
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",
           BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
           ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json
)]
```

See [jQuery AJAX calls to a WCF REST Service](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/324917.aspx) for more info.

Comment: I added the attribute but i still get an error - unfortunately the error i now get is empty so i can't see what the new problem is. I even tried adding "RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json"